# Way to figure address routing distance between geocodes?

Tags: distance, routes

Is there any algorithm out there that will help give a more accurate driving distance number between two geocodes.  Right now, most numbers just give a straight line number, and that may be the only way.  If you type in two addresses, the straight line distance may be 15 miles, but if you put in the addresses in Google Maps or any of the others, you will see that the route driving distance is more like 21 miles.

So I am wondering if anyone knows of a way of getting a number closer to the route driving distance?  I am trying to get a closer number to using Google/Mapquest/Bing APIs, without using an API if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll obviously need a street map database similar to what Google has.  They are huge and a giant pain to maintain.  Then you'll need a fairly complex path finding algorithm.

Best bet is to use the Google Maps API and let them do the leg work for you.

For comparison, check out Bing Maps and Yahoo Maps (both have API's similar to Google's)

I've also heard that ArcGIS has similar API to Bing but is MUCH cheaper ($2,500 instead of $8,000 per million transactions)

Comment: I am trying to do this without having to buy a Premium license which can cost more than $10k dollars, that's why I am looking for options.

Comment: Either you'll spend $10k on a license to use someones API, or you'll spend more on a Map database (and then pay again to keep it updated)  Using a major provider's Map API will beat any homegrown option.

Comment: Also, i think what I am trying to figure out is when I run the equation of two sets of geocodes, the distance is 15.089 miles, when i run it in google maps, the routing distance is 21.5 miles.  So the straight line distance is only 70% of the actual road distance.  I am wondering if there is a percentage number that can be "tacked" on to make it closer to the road distance.

Comment: Jeff, that % would be different for every route.  It depends on the roads between two locations, which is why an algorithm alone cannot find the driving distance.  For example, the straight line distance between two points on the same, straight road, will be the same as the driving distance.